# how to populate field of one collection with count query results of another collection?

Tags: mongodb

Kind of a complex one here and i'm pretty new to Mongo, so hopefully someone can help. I have a db of users. Each user has a state/province listed. I'm trying to create another collection of the total users in each state/province. Because users sign up pretty regularly, this will be an growing total i'm trying to generate and display on a map.

I'm able to query the database to find total number of users in a specific state, but i want to do this for all users and come out with a list of totals in all states/provinces and have a separate collection in the DB with all states/provinces listed and the field TOTAL to be dynamically populated with the count query of the other collection. But i'm not sure how to have a query be the result of a field in another collection.

used this to get users totals:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$state", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

My main question is how to make the results of a query the value of a field in each corresponding record in another collection. Or if that's even possible.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that [On-Demand Materialized Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/) (just added on version 4.2 of MongoDB) should solve your problem!

You can create an On-Demand Materialized View using the [$merge operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge).

A possible definition of the Materialized View could be:

```
updateUsersLocationTotal = function() {
   db.users.aggregate( [
      { $match: { <if you need to perform a match, like $state, otherwise remove it> } },
      { $group: { _id:"$state", users_quantity: { $sum: 1} } },
      { $merge: { into: "users_total", whenMatched: "replace" } }
   ] );
};
```

And then you perform updates just by calling `updateUsersLocationTotal()`

After that you can query the view just like a normal collection, using `db.users_total.find()` or `db.users_total.aggregate()`.